# how to intecept undefined routes

Tags: flask

I can define many routes in flask

```
@app.route('/')

@app.route('/schedules/<params>', methods=["GET"])
```

but how to intercepted any other routes that not defined in my app.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following ?

```
@app.route('/<generic>')
```

You may also be looking for a way to handle 404 errors

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a catch_all functionality that will take the path requested and try to return an html file with that name, if it fails it will redirect to index.

```
@WebApp.app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
   def catch_all(path):
      url = path+".html"
      try:
         return flask.render_template(url)
      except:
         return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
```